# Python using openpyxl, load_workbook, grab pattern, and print value of cell

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, iterator, openpyxl

I'm still new to Python while exploring, learning, and today I'm working with openpyxl. How do I print a cell value (in this case date) based on the last position of my pattern? I have a worksheet I am trying grab data from row by row since my data set is less then 15 rows totals. The data looks as follows:

```
Apps, 11/3/2017, 11/4/2017, 11/5/2017, 11/6/2017, 11/7/2017, 11/8/2017...
app_1, a, a, a, b, c,d,e...
app_2, a,b,c,d,e....
app_3, a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,e,e,e,e....
```

I am able to grab each row, store it into a variable, get the value of cell, and get cell coordinates. For example, I want to 1) look at the Apps column, 2) note app_1, 3) locate letter pattern "aaa", 4) note last coordinate of "aaa" and print date to a new cell of 11/5/2017. Here is a sample of my code so far:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']

row1 = ws1.iter_rows(min_row=1,max_row=1)
row2 = ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2,max_row=2)
row3 = ws1.iter_rows(min_row=3,max_row=3)

def row_one_apps_dates(): # I have this for each row
for row in row1:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value =='a' :
            print(cell.column, cell.row)#print(cell.coordinate)

def row_two():
for row in row2:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value =='a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e':
            print(cell.column, cell.row)#print(cell.coordinate)
```

My Output:

```
A 2
B 2
C 2
D 2
E 2
F 2
```

Thank you for any help as I continue to grow in python.

**UPDATE1:**

At this point I am trying to retrieve the last value, but keep getting multiple results instead of the last one. Here is my code:

```
for row in row2:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 'a':
            result = cell.column
            last_result = result[-1]
            print(last_result)
```

OUTPUT:

```
B
C
D
E
F
G
None
```

I want to retrieve G only and will later add 1 making it G1. Grab value of G1 which would be a date.

Comment: I don't really understand the question but `cell.offset()` might be what you're looking for. BTW. the logic in `row_two()` is heavily flawed.

Comment: Thanks!! Basically, I get each cell coordinate that contains "a" in a row. I want to grab the very last "a" instance coordinates ([-1:]?). Row 1 has dates and I need to grab the column coordinate (from "a" list of coordinates) and add a 1 to it to reference the date. Later I plan to write that date to another field